# Excel's plugin for Budget?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Information:
In a company, there are 6 people who use Excel to create budget. Unfortunately, there are lots of different copy of that file.

Problem statement:
I'am looking for a plug-in for excel that is linked to SQL server database. If you create a budget in excel, the data shall be saved in SQL server and it shall be easier for 6 people to edit and read the budget without having duplicate.

The data from the database shall be used for ETL process in data warehouse.

Any recommended plugin or similiar for Excel?

Comment: why not just utilize the built in sharing capabilities of Excel?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a tutorial for it?

Comment: What version of excel are you on?

Comment: It is Excel 2010.

Comment: Here are the directions for sharing in excel 2010:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the excel spreadsheet on a shared drive and set the properties to "Shared" - this will allow multiple people to edit it at the same time.  The exact location in the menus has changed several times so is version dependent, (but search the help for shared workbook), and all of the staff need to be using the same version of excel for this to work properly but it is far simpler than using a database.

Comment: Thank your for your help!
My second request is to make the data to be applied to SQL server in relation to business intelligence.

Comment: @FullMetalGame: Please ask that second question at http://superuser.com